# Python: keep top Nth results for csv.reader

Tags: python, filtering

I am doing some filtering on csv file where for every title there are many duplicate IDs with different prediction values, so the column 2 (pythoniac) is different. I would like to keep only 30 lowest values but with unique ID. I came to this code, but I don't know how to keep lowest 30 entries.

Can you please help with suggestions how to obtain 30 unique by ID entries?

```
# title1    id1 100 7.78E-25 # example of the line

with open("test.txt") as fi:
    cmp = {}
    for R in csv.reader(fi, delimiter='\t'):
        for L in ligands:
            newR = R[0], R[1]
            if R[0] == L:
                if (int(R[2]) <= int(1000) and int(R[2]) != int(0) and float(R[3]) < float("1.0e-10")):
                    if newR in cmp:
                        if float(cmp[newR][3]) > float(R[3]):
                            cmp[newR] = R[:-2]
                    else:
                        cmp[newR] = R[:-2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something along this line...

```
from bisect import insort

nth_lowest = [very_high_value] * 30

for x in my_loop:
    do_stuff()
    ...
    if x < nth_lowest[-1]:
        insort(nth_lowest, x)
        nth_lowest.pop() # remove the highest element
```